# Prevent text from wrapping underneath an image

Tags: html, css, html-table

Look into the first `td` of the table having image and text.

When text completes the line and wraps, I then want it to NOT start below the image.

The next line of text should start after the image, meaning no text should appear below the image.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:200px;">
      <img src="/images/driveicon.png">My Name is tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex layout inside the table cell to force the image and text into separate boxes:

```css
td:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; /* prevent image from stretching */
  width: 200px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/driveicon.png">
      My Name is tester tester tester tester tester
      tester tester tester tester tester tester
    </td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

OR, you could put the text in a separate table cell:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/driveicon.png">
    </td>
    <td>My Name is tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Answer revised. Included image without `stretch` feature.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
    <td style="width:200px;"><img src="/images/driveicon.png">My Name is tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester tester </td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is to set td that contains image flex display:

```
td.imageContainer{
   display: flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
}
```